# For multiple languages, two wordpress instances on subdomains or a plugin?

Tags: multi-language

I have a site in german, and the idea now is to make an english version of it.

I can't decide which approach to take.
I tend to avoid installing plugins (something doesn't feel right about it), I know that there are plugins for making site translations but I also could create a subdomain (en.domain.com) and install under this subdomain a new wordpress instance. Thinking on performance and SEO, what is the best option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking if too many plugins is bad for performance? Or are you asking wether you should use a plugin or create a new site? We have a 1 question per question policy, and you need a specific question. If you have multiple questions you should create multiple questions

Comment: Thank you, didn't knew that. I will fix it.